# How to get number of users from Siebel CRM base?

Tags: crm, siebel

I want to extract number of authenticated users in Siebel application tool for its CRM financial service.

Comment: Voting to close as not containing sufficient information to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to log into Siebel servermgr console. Then run

list sessions for comp component_alias_name

where the component_alias_name is you FINS OM. It will list out all users still logged into OM.